# merging arrays to each other

Tags: php

I have these two arrays. I want array `b` to be merged into array 1 and `apples` show under `product[0]`, `oranges` in `product[1]` and `lemon` in `product[2]`:

```
$a = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46714
        )
        [Product] => Array
        (
            [id] => 148  
        )
    )       
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46714              
        )
        [Product] => Array
        (
            [id] => 148
        )   
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46714                           
        )
        [Product] => Array
        (
            [id] => 148  
        )
    )
)

$b = array(     
    [0] => apples
    [1] => Orange
    [2] => Lemon
)
```

Comment: Or have you just forgotten to show array `$b` and therefore made the question impossible to answer?

Comment: sorry just added array b

Comment: Show in the product how? Replacing it, another field next to ID (if so, called what)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like?

```
foreach ($b as $key => $value)
{
  $a[$key]['product'][] = $value;  
}
```

You need to specify your desired result for a more accurate guess.

Comment: hmm, using $k in my example would be easier yes, haha :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($b as $key => $value) {
  $a[$key]['fruit'] = $value;
}
```

That would add them based on the current order. Giving you $a[0]['fruit'] = Apples, $a[1]['fruit'] = Orange and $a[2]['fruit'] = "Lemon". I'm not sure if that's what you need, can't completely understand your question.

Comment: `$k` would equal `$i` in this case, and has to, potentially skipping values, so I would dispense with `$i` entirely.  I would upvote this, but not with single letter variables, using the `['fruit']` key is actually better than the other answer however.

Comment: yeah, I noticed jeroen's post with the $k part. I've changed the code with your notes.

Comment: @Orbling, @PENDO I kind of agree, but in the end this is a guessing game; without information about the desired result we can add keys, name keys, put them under `product`, next to `product`, etc.

Comment: I agree, but just to keep a relation to the values he's trying to add fruit makes it a little bit more clear. You were right on the $key part tho, completely missed it. Just wondering if both arrays are always of the same lengt.. but with the information given this is the best we can do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the other examples, but you could spare yourself an unneeded iteration by modifying your $b array and merging the two:

```
// Modify your $b array to mimic the structure of your $a array
$b = array(     
    [0] => array('Product' => 'apples'),
    [1] => array('Product' => 'Orange'),
    [2] => array('Product' => 'Lemon')
);

// Merge the two arrays into $a
$a = array_merge($a, $b);
```

Generally it's best to use PHP's compiled code as it will out perform any code you can write yourself.